# How to check if radiobutton is uncheked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery script that reads the value of a checkbox. This is fine when I have 1 value and rest hide other value. Now I'm looking for a solution when the checkbox has no value. If has no value hide. Here is my solution.

```
$("[name$='RadioButtonChoiceField']:checked").each(function(){
    var val = $(this).val()

    if(val != "need"){
        $(this).closest("table").closest("tr").hide();
    }
});
```

Update[Picture of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGXfN.jpg)

Comment: Please share your HTML

Comment: You title say you want to find radiobutton that is unchecked, and your content say you want to find checkbox that has no value? What is your actual question

Comment: See picture. If item5 unchecked hide.